# SQL query to patching text fields in Database where text contains specific string

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

I have a table with a text field `info` which contains text and urls. Something like `

```
Sometext <_a href="https://Asite.com/path">Link<_/a> sometext
```

I want to patch this text field and get

`Sometext <_a href="https://Bsite.com/path">Link<_/a> sometext`

I want to go through all these text fields and change all links inside the column `info`.
Is there any SQL condition to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL Replace() function. Like this:

```js
UPDATE TestTable
SET info = REPLACE(info, 'https://Asite.com/path', 'https://Bsite.com/path')
WHERE info like '%https://Asite%'
```

More information on the Replace keyword here - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp